# Why is temporary object living after end of the expression

Tags: c++, temporary-objects, const-reference

Why if

```
string getString(){
    return string("string");
}

int main(){
const string& a = getString();
    cout << a;
}
```

Will give an UB

This:

```
class vector{
void push_back(const T& value){
        //...
        new(arr + sz) T (value);
        ++sz;

    }
}

main(){
vector v;
v.push_back(string("abc"));
}
```

will be OK?

I guess that in first case temporary object expires right after end of the expression `const string& a = getString();` Whereas in second case temporary object's life will be prolonged until finish of the function.
Is it the only one case of prolonging of temporary object's life behind of an expression.

Comment: First example is not UB AFAIK.

Comment: `const string& a = getString();` is not UB as the lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the life time of `a`.  _"...The lifetime of a temporary object may be extended by binding to a const lvalue reference or to an rvalue reference (since C++11), see reference initialization for details...."_ source https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case I**:

> I guess that in first case temporary object expires right after end of the expression const string& a = getString();

Note that,

> const references are allowed to bind to temporaries. Also, const references extend the lifetime of those temporaries.

For example,

```
const int &myRef = 5;
```

Here the reference `myRef` extend the lifetime of the temporary `int` that was materialized using the **prvalue** expression 5 due to **temporary materialization**.

Similarly in your first code snippet, the function `getString()` returns a `std::string` **by value**. The lifetime of the temporary that is materialised in this case will also be extended.

So your first code snippet has no UB.

You asked

> Is it the only one case of prolonging of temporary object's life behind of an expression.

No there are other examples like the one i have given(`const int &myRef = 5;`).